# How to customize logistic regression for this case?

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, binary-classification

I have a binary classification problem, with a dataset comprising of several features. When I train `LogisticRegression` on it, I get large number of false positives and false negatives. This is totally ok, however I would like to train my model such that the data which consists of larger feature value of some specific feature `f1` is given more weightage, with weight proportional to value of `f1`. The end goal is to train the model to be more precise on data where feature `f1` is large such that false positives and false negatives contain mostly the ones with lower `f1` values. Is there any way to approach this problem?

Comment: A suggestion: pick a different name from f1, as that makes it look like you want to do something with the F1 score. // Why? Part of the point of regression and even machine learning more broadly is to let the algorithm go figure out this kind of relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by weighting the samples in the loss function calculation. In `sklearn`, that's done using the `sample_weights` argument of the `fit` method. You'd set that parameter as an array, whatever function of your `f1` that's most appropriate.